# Ruby with Xcode 5

Tags: ruby, xcode

I am completely new to using ruby and Xcode but I am trying to go through the book 7 languages in 7 weeks but right now I am hung up on trying to find out how to create a ruby script using Xcode 5. If anyone knows how to point me the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use XCode? Ruby is preinstalled on Mac OS, so you can start with that without any XCode involvement. Open a terminal window, and use a text editor like vim or nano and create Ruby scripts. Save them and run them. Don't make it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I personally use vim and like it because it's the same on any computer.  TextWrangler from the Mac App store is another good text editor.  Xcode is not the tool of choice for editing Ruby scripts.  Edit your script making the first line `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, save it, make it executable with `chmod +x myscript.rb`, and then run it `./myscript.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MacRuby.  There are instructions to create a simple application [here](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Creating-a-simple-application) although the documentation references Xcode 4.6 so I don't know how you will go with version 5.